# How do I direct a Perl script to check for website response?

Tags: perl

I’m pinging a website and checking the availability and sending an email only when it’s down. (That part is working just fine according to the code below.)

```
require LWP::UserAgent;
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->timeout(20);
my $response = $ua->get('https://www.Mysite.net/websuite/');
if (! $response->is_success) {
    #print 'CMM Is up and Running';  
    $path = "C:\\prac\\send_email_failure.ps1";
    $pwspath = "c:\\windows\\system32\\windowspowershell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe";
    system("$pwspath -command $path"); #using powershell to invoke email utility      
}
```

Now, I’m working on trying to expand the script to see whether

1. It can check once it’s down  and send email (which it’s doing now) and don’t send email until it’s bought up. By the way, I’m using Windows task scheduler to run the script every twenty minutes.
2. After it sees the website is up it should goto its normal process of checking whether the site is down again and send email (for example the website went down then bought back up and again went down). I’m running the script every 20 mins using task scheduler.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: i think you'll have to store somewhere what was the status of the last attempt. and then, if last_attemps is succes and current attempt is faillure, then send an email.

Comment: You might be better off installing something like nagios or monit. These let you monitor various services and send alerts or perform other actions (e.g. restart the service).

Answer (score 1):

If your script is executed from some kind of scheduler you'll need to persist the status of your last request somehow. You could for example create a file which flags the last status as "down".

Or you could simply run your script as a daemon and schedule a check every 20 minutes (for example with [AnyEvent](https://metacpan.org/module/AnyEvent)). This way you wouldn't have to cope with filesystem related issues.

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
use AnyEvent;

my $previous = 1;
my $watch = AnyEvent->timer(interval => 1200, cb => sub {
        if(check_status() == 0) {
            if($previous == 1) {
                # send e-mail
            }
            $previous = 0;
        }
        else {
            $previous = 1;
        }
    });

AnyEvent->condvar->recv;

sub check_status {
    my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(timeout => 20);
    my $response = $ua->get('...');
    return $response->is_success ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Comment: You will need to [install](http://www.cpan.org/modules/INSTALL.html) the AnyEvent module from CPAN if you want to try this code example.